# How to test a Non Thread safe class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Threads. I am reading Java Concurrency in Practice. I found the following example in the book.

```
@NotThreadSafe
public class UnSafeSequence
{
     private int value;
     public int getNext()
     {
         return value++;
     }
}
```

I wanted to test this code by writing couple of threads(or more) accessing this class to get a feeling of thread safety.

I tried like these, but not sure really how to test these examples.

```
class MyThread implemented Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        //Should I create a new object for UnSafeSequence here ?
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem with non-threadsafe code is that the code can execute n times and can still produce the correct result n times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I wanted to test this code by writing couple of threads(or more) accessing this class to get a feeling of thread safety.

If each thread has its own instance of `UnSafeSequence` then it won't demonstrate the problem.  What you need to do is to create an instance of `UnSafeSequence` outside of your `MyThread` instances and pass it into the constructor of each `MyThread`.

```
 UnSafeSequence unsafe = new UnSafeSequence();
 ...
 new Thread(new MyThread(unsafe)).start();
 new Thread(new MyThread(unsafe)).start();
 ...
 class MyThread implemented Runnable {
       private UnSafeSequence unsafe;
       public MyThread(UnSafeSequence unsafe) {
            this.unsafe = unsafe;
       }
       public void run() {
            ...
            unsafe.getNext();
            ...
       }
 }
```

While you are learning about threads, be sure to read about the `ExecutorService` and other great classes.  Here's a [good tutorial from Sun^H^H^H Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Answer (score 2):

No, if you create a new instance of `UnSafeSequence` in `run` each thread will have its own `value` member and this will not show a problem. You have 2 options:

- Make `value` and `getNext()` static and call it with `UnSafeSequence.getNext()`
- Create a shared object and pass it to your threads upon creation

  ```
  class MyThread implemented Runnable
  {
     UnSafeSequence unsafe;
     MyThread(UnSafeSequence unsafe) { this.unsafe = unsafe; }
     public void run() { /* call unsafe.getNext(); */ }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single `UnSafeSequence` instance per thread, and that will be completely safe.  If you do that for N threads, you will have N copies of value, which is the non-synchronized data in question.

If you want to access it in a thread unsafe manner, you need to create a single instance of `UnSafeSequence` and then call getNext() from multiple threads.